# How do I transfer (to a usb drive) or read a .odt file in the command-line?

Tags: command-line, files, mount, usb-drive

Currently my computer is not allowing me to start it up properly (guessing my hard drive is malfunctional), but I've figured out that Ctrl+Alt+(F1,F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,OR F7) allows me to access command-line. So I was hoping that being able to do that would allow me to get all the necessary information from a specific file. If there is a way, and you know it, please let me know here. I'll try anything and post the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the user you are using, you may need to type `su -` or `sudo` first to get `root` privileges.

Type `lsblk`:

```
> lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  1020K  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    41G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0    11G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0    19G  0 part /
├─sda5   8:5    0  33,6G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0     2G  0 part 
├─sda7   8:7    0     2G  0 part 
└─sda8   8:8    0     2G  0 part
```

Insert an **usb drive** and type `lsblk` again.

```
> lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 111,8G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0  1020K  0 part 
├─sda2   8:2    0    41G  0 part 
├─sda3   8:3    0    11G  0 part 
├─sda4   8:4    0    19G  0 part /
├─sda5   8:5    0  33,6G  0 part 
├─sda6   8:6    0     2G  0 part 
├─sda7   8:7    0     2G  0 part 
└─sda8   8:8    0     2G  0 part 
sdb      8:16   0 931,5G  0 disk 
├─sdb1   8:17   0     4G  0 part 
├─sdb2   8:18   0     4G  0 part 
├─sdb3   8:19   0     4G  0 part 
└─sdb4   8:20   0 919,5G  0 part
```

Identify one partition inside the **usb drive**, on this case `/dev/sdb4`

Create a directory, mount `/dev/sdb4`, copy the **.odt file**, umount `/dev/sdb4` and remove the directory:

```
> mkdir dir
> mount /dev/sdb4 dir
> cp file.odt dir/
> rmdir dir
```

Comment: Or just plug the drive in and read `dmesg`...

Comment: So far I remember, with `dmesg` he/she would see only the drive letter, but not the partition numbers and sizes :(

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, but it would have been helpful for you to let me know that some of those commands needed to be done as Root (or w/ sudo) :)

Comment: @DeJeL! Thank you very much for yur feedback! Unfortunately I had no way to know it, because I use `debian` as root. However, your comment helps me to try to increase the quality of further answers : )

Answer (score 0):

[WordGrinder](http://cowlark.com/wordgrinder/index.html) lets you view .odt files (text content only, naturally) in the console:

[image: WordGrinder]